# RC response for any given voltage

Tags: circuit-analysis, math, remote-control, physics

Lets imagine a simple RC circuit in which the response voltage is defined by the following equation:

$$
V(t) = V_{inf} \cdot (1-\exp(-t/\tau)
$$

This is only true when a constant voltage is applied (switched on) at t=0.

Let's imagine now a voltage source that produces a periodic squarewave, a triangular wave or even any variying voltage \$V_s(t)\$. (The time has to reset to zero every time that the voltage source changes.) How can I obtain a mathematical expression that gives the response voltage over time of any given voltage applied over time?

Comment: The Laplace transform would be helpful here.

Comment: @Hearth yes indeed!

Answer (score 1):

> or even any variying voltage \$Vs(t)\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnzrUj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$
\begin{aligned}
v_s(t)&=i(t)\cdot R + v_c(t) \\ 
\Rightarrow v_s(t) &=\Bigg(C \ \frac{dv_c(t)}{dt}\Bigg)\cdot R+v_c(t) \\
\Rightarrow 0 &= RC \ \frac{dv_c(t)}{dt}+v_c(t) - v_s(t)
\end{aligned}
$$

You'll need to solve this differential equation for \$v_c(t)\$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, notice that the voltage across the capacitor is given by:

$$
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{V}_\text{C}\left(t\right)&=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\text{v}_\text{C}\left(\text{s}\right)\right]_{\left(t\right)}\\
\\
&=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\text{z}_\text{C}\left(\text{s}\right)\cdot\text{i}_\text{in}\left(\text{s}\right)\right]_{\left(t\right)}\\
\\
&=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\text{z}_\text{C}\left(\text{s}\right)\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\text{v}_\text{in}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{z}_\text{in}\left(\text{s}\right)}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\\
\\
&=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\text{v}_\text{in}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}+\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}}}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\\
\\
&=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\displaystyle\text{v}_\text{in}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{sCR}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{sC}}{\displaystyle\text{sC}}}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\\
\\
&=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\displaystyle\text{v}_\text{in}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{sCR}+1}\right]_{\left(t\right)}
\end{alignat*}
\tag1
$$

Using the [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) of the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform), we can write:

$$
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{V}_\text{C}\left(t\right)&=\int\limits_0^t\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\text{v}_\text{in}\left(\text{s}\right)\right]_{\left(\tau\right)}\cdot\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sCR}+1}\right]_{\left(t-\tau\right)}\space\text{d}\tau\\
\\
&=\int\limits_0^t\text{V}_\text{in}\left(\tau\right)\cdot\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sCR}+1}\right]_{\left(t-\tau\right)}\space\text{d}\tau\\
\\
&=\int\limits_0^t\text{V}_\text{in}\left(\tau\right)\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\exp\left(\frac{\displaystyle\tau-t}{\displaystyle\text{CR}}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{CR}}\space\text{d}\tau\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{CR}}\int\limits_0^t\text{V}_\text{in}\left(\tau\right)\exp\left(\frac{\displaystyle\tau-t}{\displaystyle\text{CR}}\right)\space\text{d}\tau
\end{alignat*}
\tag2
$$

---

**Edit**, let's do an example. A [triangle wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave) can be defined using a [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series):

$$x\left(t\right)=-\frac{\displaystyle8}{\displaystyle\pi^2}\sum_{\text{n}\space\ge\space1}\frac{\displaystyle\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\displaystyle\left(2\text{n}-1\right)^2}\cdot\sin\left(2\pi\left(2\text{n}-1\right)t\right)\tag3$$

So, we get:

$$
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{V}_\text{C}\left(t\right)&=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{CR}}\int\limits_0^t\left(-\frac{\displaystyle8}{\displaystyle\pi^2}\sum_{\text{n}\space\ge\space1}\frac{\displaystyle\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\displaystyle\left(2\text{n}-1\right)^2}\cdot\sin\left(2\pi\left(2\text{n}-1\right)\tau\right)\right)\exp\left(\frac{\displaystyle\tau-t}{\displaystyle\text{CR}}\right)\space\text{d}\tau\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle8}{\displaystyle\text{CR}\pi^2}\sum_{\text{n}\space\ge\space1}\frac{\displaystyle\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\displaystyle\left(2\text{n}-1\right)^2}\int\limits_t^0\sin\left(2\pi\left(2\text{n}-1\right)\tau\right)\exp\left(\frac{\displaystyle\tau-t}{\displaystyle\text{CR}}\right)\space\text{d}\tau
\end{alignat*}
\tag4
$$